# Can't get app.config value "connectionStrings"?

Tags: c#

I am writing a program in visual studio,now i can't get the value of app.config.My app.config look like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>  
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="connStr" connectionString="Data Source=Dolphin-PC;Initial Catalog=jsptpd_SYS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ccir"/>
        </connectionStrings>        
    </configuration>
```

And the code i am try to get the value:

```
          try
            {
              con2 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
                logger.Info("try to get connectionstr success:" + connStr);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Info("try to get connectionstr failed:" + ex.ToString());
            }
```

The log's output:

```
 2013-12-14 16:22:28,710 [1] INFO  ApplicationInfoLog [(null)] <(null)>     
 - try to get connectionstr failed:System.NullReferenceException:     
   object reference not set to instance. 
   on Jsptpd.JobScheduler.jsptpdJobScheduler..ctor() 
   location D:\jsptpd\Code\jsptpdJobScheduler\jsptpdJobScheduler\jsptpdJobShedule.cs:line  46
```

Where is wrong? Why can't read the ConnectionStrings?

Comment: Looks like you have serious problems to craft a well formed xml document. You should start there

Comment: @hek2mgl the problem is not there,even change the <configration>,but that is one of the error.I've debug 1 day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your section is declared as NameValueSectionHandler. As this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903356%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) points out, this handler returns a NameValueCollection, not the IDictionary that you cast it to afterwards. That's why `as IDictionary` results in a null value.
Either declare your section as DictionarySectionHandler or change IDictionary to NameValueCollection.

Comment: I changed ,but still can not get the value

Comment: Where is wrong,what situation can cause ConfigurationManager can't get the configration value?

Comment: In which direction have you changed it? Is the message the same? It is always easier to inspect such things in the debugger. Can you attach a debugger and describe the error in greater detail? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 1):

If that config you posted is really what you have, then that config is just plain wrong.... you have **two nested** `<configuration>` sections - that won't ever work!

If your config really looks like what you posted, you need to change it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>            <!-- one and ONLY one <configuration> node! -->
   <configSections>        <!-- directly under <configuration> -->
      <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
   <configSections>

   <connectionStrings>     <!-- directly under <configuration> -->
       <add name="connStr" connectionString="Data Source=Dolphin-PC;Initial Catalog=jsptpd_SYS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ccir"/>
   </connectionStrings>

   <quartz>                <!-- directly under <configuration> -->
      ...........
   </quartz>    

   <appSettings>           <!-- directly under <configuration> -->
       <add key="connStr" value="Data Source=Dolphin-PC;Initial Catalog=jsptpd_SYS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ccir"/>
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

There should be only **one** `<configuration>` section, and all other tags, like `<configSections>`, `<quartz>`, `<connectionStrings>` and `<appSettings>` should be directly inside the one and only `<configuration>` element

Comment: Yes, i have two nest configSection,and  i will change and try

Comment: @Dolphin: no, you have **two nested `<configuration>`** elements, and that's not a valid .NET configuration file

Comment: Thank for remind me. But i am not sure your suggestion will work,i am trying like what you say

Comment: @Dolphin: the easiest way to find out is : you try it, and you report back if it worked (or not).

Comment: It still that problem,have you ever configuration quartz.net program? I send the program to you?

Comment: @marc_s with 200k+ reputation you should have voted for closing this question. (please check your profile :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your app.config file attribute set,make sure that Generate Operation is **not embeded resource**.

Because you read the app.config through ConfiguationManager class,the Configuration read file like this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

•Read and write configuration files as a whole. Your application can read and write configuration settings at any level, for itself or for other applications or computers, locally or remotely. Use one of the methods provided by the ConfigurationManager class to open a configuration file such as SampleApp.exe.config. These methods return a Configuration object that in turn exposes methods and properties you can use to work with the associated configuration files. The methods perform read or write operations and create the configuration data every time that a file is written.

If you set **embeded resource**,the bin directionary could not generate the **SampleApp.exe.config** file,so the ConfigurationManager could read your config file.

So if you want to correct the problem,do this

choose the `app.config` file in resource manager of visual studio:

set the copy to `outout dirctionary` to:

```
No copy
```

set the `generte operation` to:

```
None
```

The problem will fixed.